# Markdown not parsed correctly when coming from json

Tags: javascript, markdown, vue.js

I have some markdown to parse with markdown-it and markdown-it-attrs (so I can have some class and attributes on elements).

Point is, if I use this :

```
md.render('foo {.bar}')
```

It renders :

```
<p class="bar">foo</p>
```

Which is good.

But then, if I use a variable, coming from a json, it's not parsed anymore:

```
md.render(post.content)
```

It renders :

```
<p>foo {.bar}</p>
```

Even if `console.log(post.content)` returns `'foo {.bar}'`, the exact same string I used in the first test…

I've no idea why it don't consider those two strings the same way.

Thanks for any help or clue!

**EDIT**
[Markdown not parsed correctly when coming from json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162113/markdown-not-parsed-correctly-when-coming-from-json/39167059#39167059) I found what was going on. Thanks!

Comment: keep it in a variable and then pass in the render method.. also try convert post.content.toString()

Comment: Does `md.render(JSON.parse(post.content))` fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what was going on, and it’s fairly stupid.

The point is that the JSON is already a parsed markdown, so the `post.content` isn’t `'foo {.bar}'`, it already has a tag : `'<p>foo {.bar}</p>'`. That’ why it couldn’t be parsed properly.

Thanks for your help!